# Dump CUPS jobs (printed document) to file

Tags: linux, cups

How to create a copy of each file being sent to CUPS server? I would like to create a copy of each file that what was sent by users to server (something like `cp /run/cups/job_01/document /root/documents_archive/`) .

Answer (score 1):

CUPS (Common Unix Printing System) keeps its files in `/var/spool/cups`. The `c*` files are CUPS control files, and the `d*` files are the data to be printed.

Noticing the creation of a file is done with the `iwatch` package, which can be installed via `sudo apt install iwatch`. Read `man inotify iwatch`.